# Basic addition of integers won't print in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

If I do a simple

```
print('hello world')
```

sublime text will show the output as normal. However, if I do:

```
28 + 7
```

it wont show anything. Not an error message or anything, its just blank.

I am making sure to use the correct build system, and I save my files with a .py to make sure they are running in python code. I have been using Sublime text for days now with no issues. The only thing I changed recently was installing 'pip' upon the advisory of "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python". I did this carefully and pip installed normally as well.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get output in Sublime Text 3 text editor or IDE

You have to provide `print(28+7)` in your python file

eg:

In `file.py` file write below two line and save it.And run using `Ctrl+b`

`print("Hello World")`

`print(28+7)`

Comment: Oh god that seems simple - I wish I thought of that. I was following the book word for word, I think the book mentioned using the editor "Mu", but I am most comfortable with sublime 3. Maybe that makes a difference? The book didn't show any print command. Thank you a bunch!

Comment: @Sabrina May be book is asking to run your code in python interpreter and you are using IDE i.e sublime 3.In python interpreter without using print() you will get output:
Just open go to command prompt and type python , click there it will open python interpreter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to print out the result. E.g:

```
sum = 28 + 7
print(sum)
```

OR

```
print(28+7)
```

Comment: Oh god that seems simple - I wish I thought of that. I was following the book word for word, I think the book mentioned using the editor "Mu", but I am most comfortable with sublime 3. Maybe that makes a difference? The book didn't show any print command. Thank you a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome! You can also accept answers to say "thanks" in Stack Overflow :)